# Plot all the components of a PCA

Tags: r, plot, pca

I'd like to know how can we do to plot the individual in more than the first and second component, like this :

[image]

Comment: How do you group the points in each panel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work:

```
pc.cr <- princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)
pairs(pc.cr$loadings, col=c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use `splom` from `lattice` package. Here I use :

1. `splom` for matrix scatter plot
2. `prcomp` to compute PCA
3. `mclustBIC` to cluster data. since you need to group points by some criteria. Note that giving only color will just recycle the col argument.

You can write for example :

```
library(lattice)
library(mclust)
dat <- iris[,1:4]
dat.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])
dat.em <- mclustBIC(dat) 
splom(as.data.frame(dat.pca$x), 
      col=summary(dat.em,data=dat)$classification, cex=2,pch='*')
```

[image]